# Object value as null in Jackson Parsing

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jackson

I am using Jackson library and trying to achieve that is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294343/how-do-i-parse-a-json-array-into-different-objects-using-jackson-on-android)

**BaseOperationRequest.java**

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
   use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
   include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
   property = "command"
)
@JsonSubTypes({
   @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "ZADD", value = ZAddBaseOperationRequest.class)
})
public class BaseOperationRequest {
   public short operationId;
   public Command command;
   public String gameId;
   public String key;
}
```

**ZAddBaseOperationRequest.java**

```
public class ZAddBaseOperationRequest extends BaseOperationRequest{
   public Map<String, Double> members;
}
```

**Command.java**

```
public enum Command{
  ZADD,
  HSET
}
```

The problem is here when I try to pass the Object from REST call which is something like this:

```
@RestController
public class MyController{
   //keeping just for now as GET, will change it to POST and take it in RequesBody later on
   @RequestMapping(value = "/process/{object}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity process(@Pathvariable String object){
        System.out.println(object);//I am getting this as correct--->(A)
        BaseOperationRequest[] baseOperationRequestArray = new ObjectMapper().readValue(object, BaseOperationRequest[].class);//getting exception --->(B)
        System.out.println(baseOperationRequestArray);
    }
}
```

Now, I am calling this as follows:

**1st scenario**
**CALLING WITHOUT MEMBERS MAP:**

```
<server>:<port>/.../process/[{"operationId":1,"command":"ZADD","gameId":"t5","key":"abc"}]
```

The **process method** is getting called and since Jackson is told to create the Object of  **ZAddBaseOperationRequest** when getting **ZADD** in command, it is doing it but the value of **command** itself is assigned as **null** in the resultant object.

Please explain why? Where did the value of **command** went?

**2nd scenario**
**CALLING WITH MEMBERS MAP:**
    :/.../process/[{"members":{"a":1.0},"operationId":1,"command":"ZADD","gameId":"t5","key":"abc"}]

then in this case, the equation (A)  is showing **[{"members":{"a":1.0,b** that's it, where did the other part of the GET went.

This is making me mad. :).
Thanks in advance..

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

> It is not a good practice to send json as path parameter.

To fix your problem add `visible=true` in `JsonTypeInfo` annotation. Your declaration will become:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
  property = "command",
  visible = true
)
```

As per jackson documentation for `visible`:

> Property that defines whether type identifier value will be passed as part of JSON stream to deserializer (true), or handled and removed by TypeDeserializer (false).
>   Default value is false, meaning that Jackson handles and removes the type identifier from JSON content that is passed to JsonDeserializer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and suggestion, I know its bad habit, that's why I wrote in that too, anyways your solution worked, +1 but because other part is not answered that's why no accept :)

Comment: what is that other part?

Comment: @ankurverma can you post exact input and output for scenario two? as per your question i was not able to understand properly.